# What is wrong with my curry leaf plant?

Tags: plant-care

My 3+ year old curry leaf plant has gotten some dark stains on some of the leaves. Some of it is on the edges and some on the inside as shown in the pictures. All pictures are of the same plant and taken the same day when I have posted this question.

I started noticing it in winter about, 5 months back, when I had moved the pot from under the tree shade into the sun. I felt like it may be burning the leaves so after about 2 months I moved it back under the tree share. It has been about 4 months and I see some improvement but I still see some of these. I would like to know whats wrong.

About the care of this plant, I usually water this plant about once a week and for compost I put in household kitchen waste like leftover/cut veggies, spoiled milk and the remains from Indian tea/chai. It is planted in a pot about 10+ inches high and the plant height is about 5+ feet.

What could be wrong with my curry leaf plant and how can I make it green and healthy back again?

Happy gardening!

[image]
[image]
[image]